# Morris donut graphs. Very long and small labels

Tags: label, morris.js, onhover, donut-chart

I have very long labels on my morris donut graphs. 
Because of their long it's very hard to read.

I would like to have some kind of popup with label when I hover on that text. But there are no css classes to bind a handler.

js code:

```
Morris.Donut({
  element: 'donut-example',
  data: [
    {label: "Download SalesD DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD", value: 12},
    {label: "In-Store Sales AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA", value: 30},
    {label: "Mail-Order Sales VVVVVVVVVVVVVVV", value: 20}
  ]
});
```

I've tried formatter, but it is not a solution.

Please give me some help.

[Here is example](http://jsbin.com/gicevaguyi/1/edit?js,output)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a long time without any answer I decide to post my own solution. I doesn't do exactly what I've asked for, but supply readable  solution.

It was done with label below the donut, instead of inside donut circle.

[Here is working solution on JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/luxizo/1/edit?html,js,output)

Below You can see a screenshot of working in app:

[image]

Here is the code:

---

JS:

```
Morris.Donut({
  element: 'morrisDonutChart',
  data: [
    {label: "Download SalesD DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD", value: 12},
    {label: "In-Store Sales AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA", value: 30},
    {label: "Mail-Order Sales VVVVVVVVVVVVVVV", value: 20}
  ]
});


$( "#morrisDonutChart" ).mouseover(function() {
    prepareMorrisDonutChart();
});

$( document ).ready(function() {
    prepareMorrisDonutChart();
});

function prepareMorrisDonutChart() {
    $("#morrisDonutChart tspan:first").css("display","none");
    $("#morrisDonutChart tspan:nth-child(1)").css("font-size","40px");

    var isi = $("#morrisDonutChart tspan:first").html();
    $('#morrisDonutChartSpan').text(isi);
}
```

HTML head:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/mootools/1.5.0/mootools-yui-compressed.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/raphael/2.1.0/raphael-min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://cdn.oesmith.co.uk/morris-0.4.1.min.js"></script>
```

HTML body:

```
  <div id="morrisDonutChart"></div>
  <div class="alert alert-info" role="alert">
    <span id="morrisDonutChartSpan"></span>
  </div>
```

I hope this will help someone.

Comment: Hi masterdany88. How would you iterate through several donuts? I've been trying to implement your method on a page that has about 10 donuts, but I can't get the logic to iterate through all of them. Would you know? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Managed to get it to work with help from your answer, Here's the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40810160/iterating-through-a-set-morris-donuts-in-asp-net-application-using-jquery-and-mo/40942562#40942562